# Javafx-Java update disables javafx

Tags: java, javafx, updates

Hello I just downloaded the latest java update - Version 8 Update 111 released today and this completely disabled javafx in my applications(by this I mean it gives me an error for all my javafx imports) is there any reason for this and anyway to fix this?

Comment: There is no stack trace. It just does not recognize javafx libraries

Comment: What version of java and fx were you using before?

Comment: I believe update 101 but I cannot quite tell.

Comment: I just tried out update 112 and it works fine. You probably forgot to adjust some class path or system variable... (At least I cannot think of a reason the behaviour would be different for Updates 111/112).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I needed to reinstall java update 101 since that was automatically uninstalled through the auto-update mechanic of java.